# Magento 2.4: Why is there a semi-transparent overlay at each side of the image?

Tags: magento2

This is an image from a product page. Notice that there's a semi-transparent overlay at each side of the image, each containing the left and right arrows.  The overlay should be eliminated, but the arrows maintained.  Can that be done?

Please note: while the cursor is over the image is the time when the overlays appear. It's on every product page with more than one image.

Link to the product page: https://www.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/serdaneli-hemisphere-limoges-porcelain-toothbrush-holder.html

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate the overlays using the below css. Add below css in theme/custom css. Thanks!

```
.fotorama__arr.fotorama__arr--next, .fotorama__arr.fotorama__arr--prev {
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I let you know if it helps. I deployed the changes but need to build the server to see the change.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, it worked.

Comment: @PKTG You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

On Css, you have this class :

```
.fotorama__arr, .fotorama__thumb__arr {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
  transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;
    transition-property: background-color;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
```

Remove `background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);` from this.